# AWK How to parse irregular file

Tags: awk

Hi I need to generate report from very huge file log. For now I wrote "one liners" in awk and it was enough for my need, now i'm stuck.

I wrote awk code:

```
awk '{if ($1 == "GR" && $4 == "NGR") {c = $3; n = $6} else if ($1 == "NAME") {m = $3} else if ($1 == "PCM-TSL" || $1 == "TERMID") {s = "1"} else if (s == "1" && $1 ~ "-") {split ($1,pcm,"-")} else if (s == "1" && p == pcm[1]) {next}  else if (c != "" && n != "" ) {p = pcm[1]; print c " " n " "m " " p  }}' DATA_FILE
```

Or broken up:

```
awk '
        {
        if ($1=="GR" && $4=="NGR") {
            c=$3
            n=$6} 
        else if ($1=="NAME") {
            m=$3} 
        else if ($1=="PCM-TSL" || $1=="TERMID") {
            s="1"} 
        else if (s=="1" && $1~"-") {
            split ($1,pcm,"-")} 
        else if (s=="1" && p==pcm[1]) {
            next}  
        else if (c!="" && n!="" ) {
            p = pcm[1]
            print c,n,m,p}
        }' DATA_FILE
```

It show data in correct format but only one record for one GR & NGR & NAME.

I need to show:

```
GR   NGR   NAME PCM
200  D200E AAA1 4
200  D200E AAA1 8
200  D200E AAA1 ...
220  DA30E BBA1 1
220  DA30E BBA1 2
...
```

There is example log:

```
 GROUP(S)
some unused data....
GR      : 200             NGR     : D200E           

NAME : AAA1
some unused data....    
DR1A  : -      DR2A  : -      ART1A : -      ART2A : -      ACT : NO 
DR1B  : -      DR2B  : -      ART1B : -      ART2B : -      ACT : NO  
DR1C  : -      DR2C  : -      ART1C : -      ART2C : -      ACT : NO 

CIRCUIT(S)

PCM-TSL              ORD      CTRL     HGR      STATE    LSI        

4-0                  1        X        1-1      ACT    -          
4-1                  2        X        1-2      ACT    -          
4-2                  3        X        1-3      ACT    -          
4-3                  4        X        1-4      ACT    -          
4-4                  5        X        1-5      ACT    -          
4-5                  6        X        1-6      ACT    -          
4-6                  7        X        1-7      ACT    -          
4-7                  8        X        1-8      ACT    -          
4-8                  9        X        1-9      ACT    -          
4-9                  10       X        1-10     ACT    -          
4-10                 11       X        1-11     ACT    -          
8-5                  6        X        1-6      ACT    -          
8-6                  7        X        1-7      ACT    -          
8-7                  8        X        1-8      ACT    -          
8-8                  9        X        1-9      ACT    -          
8-9                  10       X        1-10     ACT    -          
8-10                 11       X        1-11     ACT    -


 GROUP(S)

GR      : 220             NGR     : DA30E           

NAME : BBA1

DR1A  : -      DR2A  : -      ART1A : -      ART2A : -      ACT : NO 
DR1B  : -      DR2B  : -      ART1B : -      ART2B : -      ACT : NO  
DR1C  : -      DR2C  : -      ART1C : -      ART2C : -      ACT : NO 
some unused data....
CIRCUIT(S)

PCM-TSL              ORD      CTRL     HGR      STATE    LSI        

1-0                  1        X        1-1      ACT    -          
1-1                  2        X        1-2      ACT    -          
1-2                  3        X        1-3      ACT    -          
1-3                  4        X        1-4      ACT    -          
1-4                  5        X        1-5      ACT    -          
1-5                  6        X        1-6      ACT    -          
1-6                  7        X        1-7      ACT    -          
1-7                  8        X        1-8      ACT    -          
1-8                  9        X        1-9      ACT    -          
1-9                  10       X        1-10     ACT    -          
1-10                 11       X        1-11     ACT    -          
2-5                  6        X        1-6      ACT    -          
2-6                  7        X        1-7      ACT    -          
2-7                  8        X        1-8      ACT    -          
2-8                  9        X        1-9      ACT    -          
2-9                  10       X        1-10     ACT    -          
2-10                 11       X        1-11     ACT    -


more simmilar blocks
```

Regards Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
awk -f ext.awk DATA_FILE
```

where `ext.awk` is

```
$1 == "GR" && $4=="NGR" {
    if (f) {
        ngri[i]=j; j=0
    }
    f=0; i++; f2=1;
    g[i] = $3; 
    ngr[i] = $6
}
$1=="NAME"{
    n[i] = $3
    next
}
$1 == "PCM-TSL" || $1 == "TERMID" {
    f=1
    next
}

f && $1 ~ "-" {
    split ($1,a,"-")
    if (f2) {pcm[i,++j]=a[1]}
    else {
        if (pcm[i,j]!=a[1]) pcm[i,++j]=a[1]
    }
    f2=0
}

END {
    ngri[i]=j
    printf "GR\tNGR\tNAME\tPCM\n"
    nn=i
    for (i=1; i<=nn; i++) 
        for (j=1; j<=ngri[i]; j++) 
            print g[i], ngr[i],n[i],pcm[i,j]
}
```

Comment: It works without any changes, and is on my level to understand :). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

Here is how I understand your problem:

- If you see a line with GR and NGR, save those values
- The same goes for NAME
- PCM-TSL or TERMID marks the heading of a table
- Once a table found, you want to output the PCM value (the number before the dash of $1), but you don't want the numbers to be repeated.

## Solution

Based on my understanding of the problem, here is my solution, file *summary.awk*:

```
$1 == "GR" && $4 == "NGR" {gr = $3; ngr = $6}
$1 == "NAME" { name = $3 }

# GROUP(S) marks the end of the table
$1 == "GROUP(S)" { in_table = 0 }

# PCM-STL and TERMID marks the beginning of a table. Print the header
# Once.
$1 == "PCM-TSL" || $1 == "TERMID" {
    in_table = 1
    if (!header_printed)
        printf "%-3s %-6s %-6s %-s\n", "GR", "NGR", "NAME", "PCM"
    header_printed = 1
}

# In a table, we locate the PCM value, print it out without duplication
# To do this, we compare the current PCM to the one last found and only
# print when they differ.
in_table && $1 ~ /[0-9][0-9-]*/ {
    split($1,pcm_tsl,"-")
    pcm = pcm_tsl[1]
    if (pcm != last_pcm)
        printf "%3d %-6s %-6s %d\n", gr, ngr, name, pcm
    last_pcm = pcm
}
```

## Running

I saved the script as *summary.awk* and the data file as DATA_FILE:

```
awk -f summary.awk DATA_FILE
```

Here is the output:

```
GR  NGR    NAME   PCM
200 D200E  AAA1   4
200 D200E  AAA1   8
220 DA30E  BBA1   1
220 DA30E  BBA1   2
```

## Discussion

- I am trying to write in the clearest way possible. Please let me know if you need explanation.
- I noticed that the line containing "GROUP(S)" seems to mark the end of a table, so I used it.
- I found the tricky part is to recognize a row in the table, the expression `$1 ~ /[0-9][0-9-]*/` said "the first column must begins with a number, followed by numbers or dash."
- When a script gets a little complicated, i.e. spanning several lines, it is a good idea to save it to a file instead of having to edit the command line every time you want to make a change.

Comment: This code is almost ok (sometimes repeat the same record) i must read about tables in awk and when it will be understand for me i try to  improve this code. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach to something like this is to build an array from your input and print it every time you get to the next record. Like this (untested but should be close):

```
awk '
function prtRec(    pcm,numPcm) {
    print "GR", "NGR", "NAME", "PCM"
    numPcm = split(rec["PCM"],pcm) - 1
    for (i=1; i<=numPcm; i++) {
        print rec["GR"], rec["NGR"], rec["NAME"], pcm[i]
    }
    split("",rec)     # or delete(rec) in gawk
}

/:/ {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=3) {
        rec[$i] = $(i+2)
    }
}

/^PCM/ {
    inPcm = 1
}

inPcm && NF {
    split($1,pcmTsl,/-/)
    rec["PCM"] = rec["PCM"] pcmTsl[1] " "
}

/^[[:space:]]*]GROUP\(s\)[[:space:]]*$/ { inPcm=0; prtRec() }

END { prtRec() }

' file
```